# using mySQLdb with Kivy

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, python-3.x, kivy

I can successfully connect to my Db using python in C:/python27.

But when i run same file in kivy, it gives error

```
Import error: No module named _mysql
```

I just copied `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb` to `D:\kivy\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x64\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb`

I am sure, i need to copy few more files also, but dont know which are those files.

Direct installation from `MySQL-python-1.2.4b4.win32-py2.7.exe` always pick up `C:\Python27` from registry and there is no option to change the path to python under kivy.
Please suggest.